# How to properly save form data in local storage for later usage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to save form data (firstname and lastname) in **localstorage** once the form is submitted so that I will not have to type it again the next time I want to submit the form.

I have tried the code below but when I refreshed the page, form data is not saved on localstorage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>


<script  type="text/javascript">
  function store(){

     var firstname= document.getElementById('firstname').value;
     localStorage.setItem("firstname_data", firstname);

     var lastname= document.getElementById('lastname').value;
     localStorage.setItem("lastname_data", lastname);


var storedValue_firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstname_data");
var storedValue_lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname_data");

 alert(storedValue_firstname);
alert(storedValue_lastname);

              //document.getElementById('firstname').value = storedValue_firstname;
//document.getElementById('lastname').value = storedValue_lastname;


//window.location='/';
    }
</script>
 
<form  action="test.php" class="form1"  method="post" /> 
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" class='' placeholder="firstname" /><br>
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" class='' placeholder="lastname" /><br>



<button onclick="store()" type="button">Store Form Data</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to separate the processes of loading and storing the data. Use two functions and figure out when each one is supposed to run. https://jsfiddle.net/4qL9u1t8/ (click Run to reload page)

Comment: As it stands, this question is "debug my code for me", and is thus not useful to other readers. I think it can be closed either as Typo/Unrepro, or Needs Clarity/Detail, or Needs [mcve].

Comment: (The lack of attention to detail _and_ personal effort may be why it is attracting downvotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to use windows.onload event. When you reload the page, with this event you can check if anything is stored in the localstorage or not. if stored then will set this value to the input field as required. [see the example code here](https://jsbin.com/nofapiqapu/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>

  </head>
  <body>     
<form  action="test.php" class="form1"  method="post" /> 
<input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" class='' placeholder="firstname" /><br>
<input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" class='' placeholder="lastname" /><br>

<button onclick="store()" type="button">Store Form Data</button>
</form>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
  function store(){
     var firstname= document.getElementById('firstname').value;
     localStorage.setItem("firstname_data", firstname);

     var lastname= document.getElementById('lastname').value;
     localStorage.setItem("lastname_data", lastname);


      alert(storedValue_firstname);
      alert(storedValue_lastname);


    }
    
   window.onload = function exampleFunction() {
    var storedValue_firstname = localStorage.getItem("firstname_data");
    var storedValue_lastname = localStorage.getItem("lastname_data");
    if(storedValue_firstname) {
      document.getElementById('firstname').value = storedValue_firstname;
    }
       if(storedValue_lastname) {
      document.getElementById('lastname').value = storedValue_lastname;
    }
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```